# How to replace a React component

Tags: reactjs

I plan to have a base app where most of the components should be replaceable at a later time, depending on specific customer needs without touching the base app code. What is the best mechanism to achieve this within the React ecosystem? Is there a registry that can be updated, or any other deferred binding of components similar to the [GWT *replace-with*](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#replacement) construct? Thanks.

Update 1:
My understanding is that Dependency Injection would allow one to inject into static components. The question I'm asking is more about whether it's possible to implement a registry of sorts and compose the application via component registry keys, thus enabling later updates to specify which component that key will be resolved to. React seems to expect a static relation there, and I want it to be dynamic if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React dependency injection or similar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311081/react-dependency-injection-or-similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no central registry, but it wouldn't be too difficult to create one. Something like (sorry about mixing JS syntaxes)

```
// Registry module
var Component1 = require('component1')
var components = { Component1 }
var replace = function(name, cfn) { components[name] = cfn }

// Render module
var registry = require('registry')
var Component1 = registry.components['Component1']
render...Component1

// Override module
var registry = require('registry')
var Component1override = require('component1override')
registry.replace('Component1', Component1override)
```

The only trick is to make certain that the Override module gets loaded before the Render module.