# Dependency Injection in Stateless function is ok, but how do it in normal React Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a Stateless  function like my main component, and I'm testing DI and works, but I can't resolve same for a normal component (look second block below). I'm adding myVar parameters to the component after print states with {...store.getState()}

Stateless: it's working, i can change the order in the parameters of function.

```
const TodoApp = ({
  todos,  // order variables , it's not important with DI
  myVar,  // order variables , it's not important with DI
  visibilityFilter // order variables , it's not important with DI

}) => {
    return (
      <div> myVar: {myVar} // it's working
      </div>
    )
}
const render = () => {

  ReactDOM.render(
    // Render the TodoApp Component to the <div> with id 'root'
    <TodoApp
       {...store.getState()} myVar='value Var'
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')

  )
};

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

Normal React Component ES6: how do  Dependence Injection automatically without use props like in the block above ?

```
class TodoApp extends Component { // agregado export default
  constructor( here  ??? ) {

 }


  render() {
    return (
      <div> myVar: {this.myVar }
      </div>
    )
  };
}

const render = () => {
  console.log ( ...store.getState());
  ReactDOM.render(
    // Render the TodoApp Component to the <div> with id 'root'
    <TodoApp
       {...store.getState()} myVar='value Var'
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')

  )
};

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

Comment: this may be of assistance though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311081/react-dependency-injection-or-similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Access the injected params with** `this.props`

```
class Contacts extends React.Component {
  // You don't even need a constructor
  // constructor(props) {
  //  super(props);
  // }     

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Contacts: {this.props.myContact} </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)