# Building mature app architecture based on React/Redux with promises and dependency injection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, async-await

I'm new to React and trying to get how to build a good app architecture with it.
I also use typescript with all that features: interfaces, async-await, generics, etc. So, I'm puzzled about implementing some patterns:

1) **Dependency Injection and reusable component instances**

The first thing I can't get through is DI. Let's say we got a component class `UserProfile` that requires some dependencies like `UserProvider`. It would be perfect if the component instance (with deps injected) could be reusable, but I'm afraid it's only my dreams, not the react guys'. :)
So, I'm supposed to place this component this way:

`<UserProfile id={123} />`

Ok, what's the proper way to inject the dependency here? As an attribute like this `<UserProfile id={123} dependency={userProvider: userProviderInstance} />`?
Don't you think it is weird to put component input data, options/parameters and dependencies all together? I'd be happy if I could clearly separate them and put generic restrictions on the component class. What's the best practice?

Another side of impossibility to reuse component instances is the fact we must carry some needless objects through all the components structure just to inject them somewhere deep at the bottom. And nobody tells you what component does really use them. And try to imagine what adding a dependency to a low-level component will take in a large project. I just can't.

2) **Using Promises**

Let's consider a simple component that is supposed to render a counter: `<Counter value={123} />`. 
Now, value is got from some API by calling a method `getCounter(id: number): Promise<number>;`, so the obvious way to put all together could look like this:

```
<Counter value={await provider.getCounter(id)} />
```

But i't impossible, I know. The common practice tells us to make it through `setState` method and rerender the component after the value is received.

Now imagine that the parent component is pretty complex and has many different providers. So, the parent component may not have definite state typing. It also may be conditional, you know...

You could suggest me implement the async getting in the Counter component, but i will refuse for a simple reason: That component does not know anything about the value's origin. In other cases the value is passed directly as a number. So, do you got better ideas how to keep code clean and simple while using promises?

Please, let me know if you come across some good articles or have your own experience in solving these issues.

PS: Thanks for attention! :)

Comment: #2 is completely avoided by not placing logic with side-effects (e.g. API calls) in your `render()` function.  Async interactions with APIs are typically performed in action creators, middleware, sagas, etc. and the results propagated to components via props.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a subject of bias - so below I will give my ***very personal*** thoughts on the topic that does not pretend to be absolute truth.

1. **DI**.

This is indeed not so common pattern in react as it is in angular. But having both context and properties in components allows you to archive the same level of separation as with pure DI. Check the [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) - it will help you to get rid of passing same props through the whole component tree. There are quite a few articles on this topic already ([one](https://medium.com/@maxheiber/no-need-for-dependency-injection-in-react-components-641182760aaa), [two](https://jaysoo.ca/2015/06/09/react-contexts-and-dependency-injection/)) - check them out. Also you might be interested in reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311081/react-dependency-injection-or-similar)).

2. **Promises**

I do not really see any problem here. React has a simple concept - basically you have state and based on this state your app can render itself. Whereas [rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render) is not async operation - the [preparation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)/[update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) of the state can easily be done asynchronously and after results are [assigned](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to the corresponding parts of the state - the necessary child components will be updated automatically. If you component has no knowledge of how to obtain value - it should not try to do it in first place - value should be passed down as props.