# How to distribute dependencies within a React web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dependency-injection

I'm coming from a Java/Android world where dependency management is possible using dependency injection (Dagger/Spring). I am just getting started with react and I find myself struggling how to separate logic from the view layer. How do you handle this and how can I distribute dependecies (services, api, etc) through out my application?

Comment: This is what modules are for. You are free to use any DI/IoC library as well, React is unopinionated.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311081/react-dependency-injection-or-similar . DI pattern is commonly implemented with props in React. React context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html or Redux store http://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact#passing-the-store can also be used as a container.