# How do I manage dependencies in React & NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection, next.js

How do I manage dependency injection in React?

I come from an Angular world where all Services are Singleton classes (i.e. there is only one instance of the class throughout the application). In my React App, I have tried to abstract some of the 'Services' (i.e. things that do HTTP requests or Auth stuff) into their own classes. I'm guessing this is an anti-pattern in React.

E.g. I have a HttpService as:

```
class HttpService {
  public readonly axios = axios;

  constructor() {
    console.log('NEW HTTP SERVICE');
    this.registerInterceptors();
  }

  public registerInterceptors(): void {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(CacheRequestInterceptor);
    axios.interceptors.request.use(AuthInterceptor);
    axios.interceptors.response.use(CacheResponseInterceptor);
  }

  public get<T>(url: string, config: AxiosRequestConfig = {}): Observable<T> {
    return from(this.axios.get(url, config)).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        return res.data;
      })
    );
  }
// ... and so on
```

As you can see, I have the `console.log` in the constructor so I can track when a new instance is created. In the application logs (using Next.js) I see:

```
nextjs-ui: NEW HTTP SERVICE
nextjs-ui: event - build page: /login
nextjs-ui: wait  - compiling...
nextjs-ui: event - compiled successfully
nextjs-ui: NEW HTTP SERVICE
nextjs-ui: event - build page: /admin
nextjs-ui: wait  - compiling...
nextjs-ui: event - compiled successfully
nextjs-ui: NEW HTTP SERVICE
```

So clearly this ain't working how I want it to (I only want one instance of the HTTP Service).

What's the best way of achieving this in React? Would it be using Higher-Order-Components?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create service modules in React/Next project. If you want only one instance of the class, you need to use some global storage where you can store a reference to the class instance.

You can use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or state management libraries like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

This log doesn't prove that singleton pattern that you've implemented doesn't work. You're running the app in development mode (`next dev`) where an app compiled on every request. You need to run it in production mode (`next build` and `next start`) to test it.

```
nextjs-ui: NEW HTTP SERVICE
nextjs-ui: event - build page: /login
nextjs-ui: wait  - compiling...
nextjs-ui: event - compiled successfully
nextjs-ui: NEW HTTP SERVICE
nextjs-ui: event - build page: /admin
nextjs-ui: wait  - compiling...
nextjs-ui: event - compiled successfully
nextjs-ui: NEW HTTP SERVICE
```

[React dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30317660/5964023)